# Why Vw tdi taureg losing coolant quickly?

Tags: vw, coolant

After 5 years VW taureg tdi needs coolant added in 4 weeks and car functions fine with no signs of leakage, why?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there must be somewhere it is going.

I had one car with disappearing coolant and it had me going for weeks...

Eventually found a small, and I mean small, pinhole in one of the rubber pipes: when hot and under pressure the coolant was coming out and evaporating leaving no trace...

Replaced the pipe and all was fine.

So, get everything checked, must be going somewhere. Good luck.

Comment: Agreed, years ago I had a fuel smell and the leak was very small, and could be observed only when cold, when hot the fuel just evaporated immediately. I would have also mentioned the possibility of an internal leak via the head gasket.